# Error creating and casting an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an iterator in which I am creating an array of objects. I have to type cast them as Generics array creation is disallowed.

I am getting a run time error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LRandomizedQueueList$Node;
```

The full code of the iterator is shown below. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
   private class RandomizedQueueIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
       private Node current = first;
       private Node[] ca = (Node[])new Object[size()];
       //private Node[] ca = new Node[size()];

       private RandomizedQueueIterator() {
           if (first == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
           for (int j = 0; j < size(); j++) {
               ca[j] = current;
               current = current.next;
           }                        
           StdRandom.shuffle(ca);
           current = ca[0];
       }

       public boolean hasNext()  { return current != null; }

       public Item next() {
           if (current == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
           Item item = current.item;
           current = current.next; 
           return item;
       }
       public void remove() {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not supported");
       }
   }
```

I appreciate any help in understanding this error.

Comment: Why are you creating it as a `new Object[size()]`?  You can just do `new Note[size()]`...

Comment: Because I cannot create an array of generics. Only an array of Object can be created. If I try to do new Node[size()], it gives me an error.

Comment: Node is not a generic type here. As the exception message indicates, it's a nested class of RandomizedQueueList

Comment: @RameshManian If Node is a generic type parameter, you should clearly state it in your question. The code you posted doesn't show it.

Comment: Just posted the full iterator class codde

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
private Node[] ca = new Node[size()];
```

There is no need to cast the array when you create it. You can just create an array of `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is clear: you can't cast an `Object[]` to `Node[]`. `Object[]` is not a subclass of `Node[]`.

Replace the code by

```
private Node[] ca = new Node[size()];
```

Comment: This is not allowed in Java. It gives the error;
Error: /Users/admin/algs4/assignment2/RandomizedQueueList.java:133: generic array creation

Comment: Edit your question and post a complete example reproducing the problem. The exception message indicates that Node is a nested class of RandomizedQueueList, and not a generic type.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not realize that I could not create an array of Node, which is indeed a class inside of RandomizedQueueList.